# Historical evidence other than Bible about Jesus

Tags: life-of-jesus

As the title sugests, besides the Bible, what sources are there about the existance of Jessus Christ. 
I can imagine if someone did many miracles and would have thousands of people following him on different ocassions(like the preach on the mountain) or enter Jerusalem being cheered by the people in the city wouldn't go unnoticed.

So what historical records do we have about Jesus and/or his miracles?

Comment: Additionally, there is an entire book called "Evidence that Demands a Verdict" [link](http://www.amazon.com/Evidence-Demands-Questions-Challenging-Christians/dp/0785242198/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1363188654&sr=8-1&keywords=evidence+that+demands+a+verdict) that would be the correct source to check.

Comment: can someone point the link to the duplicate question as well. Thanks.